# Query by a model function result in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm sure this should be simple but I can't quite get it. This is Laravel 5.4

I have a 3 models, Profile, Assessment and Responses. Each Profile has many Assessments, each Assessment has Many Responses.

I want to be able to get the Profiles which have a Latest Assessment where the total score of 0; I would assume I can somehow use my Model functions (latestAssessment() and total_points()) in an Eloquent query. Something like:

```
$noscore_profiles = \App\Profile::where('latestAssessment', function($query) {
        $query->where(total_points(), '=', 0);
    })->paginate(2, ['*'], 'noscore_profiles');
```

I have tried numerous ways of doing this and just can't get my head around it.

**PROFILE:**

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['firstname', 'surname', 'gender', 'height', 'telephone', 'extension', 'start_date', 'yearly_reminder_sent'];

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsto('App\User');
}

public function assessments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Assessment');
}

public function latestAssessment() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Assessment')->latest();
}

public function responses() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Response', 'App\Assessment');
}

public function total_points() {
    $total_points = 0;
    foreach($this->responses as $response) {
        $total_points += $response->answer->points;
    }
    return $total_points;
}
}
```

**ASSESSMENT**

```
class Assessment extends Model
{

protected $fillable = ['profile_id', 'start_date', 'completion_date', 'completion_status'];

public function profile()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Profile');
}

public function review()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Review');
}

public function responses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Response');
}

public function equipment_requests()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\EquipmentRequests');
}

public function total_points() {
    $total_points = 0;
    foreach($this->responses as $response) {
        $total_points += $response->answer->points;
    }
    return $total_points;
}
}
```

**ANSWERED - THE FINAL CODE THAT WORKED:**

```
$noscore_profiles = \App\Profile::whereHas('latestAssessment', function($assessment) {
        $assessment->select('assessments.id','assessments.profile_id')
            ->join('responses','responses.assessment_id', '=', 'assessments.id')
            ->join('answers', 'answers.id', '=', 'responses.answer_id')
            ->groupBy('assessments.id','assessments.profile_id')
            ->havingRaw('SUM(answers.points) = 0');
    })->paginate(2, ['*'], 'noscore_profiles');
```

Comment: You can't use `total_points()` in your query since that needs an instance to be called and you need the result of a query to instance the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `total_points()` in your query since that needs an instance to be called and you need the result of a query to instance the model.

what you can do, is put the logic into the query itself

```php
$noscore_profiles = \App\Profile::whereHas('latestAssessment', function($assessment) {
    $assessment->whereRaw('SUM(answers.points) = 0')
        ->join('responses','response.assessment_id', '=', 'assessments.id')
        ->join('answers', 'answers.response_id', '=', 'responses.if')
        ->groupBy('assessments.id','profile_id')
        ->select('assessments.id','assessments.profile_id');
})->paginate(2, ['*'], 'noscore_profiles');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, understood that I can't use the function, however the query you have written returns an error for  Unknown column 'total_points

I've tried amending to ->selectRaw('assessments.id, SUM(answers.points) as total_points'); however this still returns an unknown column error.

Comment: @NickoBrooko oh, my bad. forgot to set the alias on the sum

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately still getting the error with the updated code:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total_points' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `profiles` where exists (select *, assessments.id, SUM(answers.points) as total_points from `assessments` inner join `responses` on `response`.`assessment_id` = `assessments`.`id` inner join `answers` on `answers`.`response_id` = `responses`.`if` where `profiles`.`id` = `assessments`.`profile_id` and `total_points` = 0 group by `assessments`.`id`))

Comment: @NickoBrooko i've put the aggregation on the where directly.

Comment: That looks better, I now get an SQL error for invalid use of group function. Also - needed to edit responses.if to responses.id

General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `profiles` where exists (select * from `assessments` inner join `responses` on `response`.`assessment_id` = `assessments`.`id` inner join `answers` on `answers`.`response_id` = `responses`.`id` where `profiles`.`id` = `assessments`.`profile_id` and SUM(answers.points) = 0 group by `assessments`.`id`))

Comment: @NickoBrooko Yeah you need to set the select to the aggregated fields (groupby), i dont remember if `profile_id` is needed too, but try with and without it in the select & groupby

Comment: Needed some slight amendments to use havingRaw instead of whereRaw but now working. Thank you!